# const_iterator and template, compilation error

Tags: c++, templates, iterator

I can't understand why the following code is not working, any idea ?

```
template <class T>
class Matrice
{
public:
...
    typedef typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator const_iterator;
    const_iterator& cend ( )
    {
        return valeurs.cend ( );
    }
...
private:
...
}
```

here's the complilator's complaint :

> /Users/Aleks/Documents/DS OO/DS OO/Matrice.h:70:16: Non-const lvalue
>   reference to type 'const_iterator' (aka '__wrap_iter')
>   cannot bind to a temporary of type 'const_iterator' (aka
>   '__wrap_iter')

Comment: Change return type to `const_iterator`: not a reference.

Comment: Yeah ! I should have read the complaint more carefully... Thanks !
Maybe you could explain me why can't it be a reference ?

Comment: Because you can't bind non-const lvalue references to temporaries? :D

Comment: Because `cend()` returns an iterator by value, not a reference to an iterator. It is illegal to bind a non-const reference to a temporary object.

Comment: @Aleks: for the reason the compiler says: it would bind to a temporary object. The value returned by `valuers.cend()` is a temporary object, and it will go out of scope when returning from your `cend()` function. Thus, you would be returning a reference to an object that has gone out of scope. Deferencing it would be Undefined Behavior.

Comment: @AndyProwl That should be an answer.

Comment: All right, my bad, i thought cend returned a reference --"
So i'll delete the dumb question.

Comment: There is value in **reading** what the compiler is trying to tell you. Absurd as it might look, it is what the compiler believes that your code does. Once you know what it thinks, you can go back to your code and understand why it believes that to be the case.

Comment: I finally won't delete the question because it's seems that I missed some things about temporary object, and it helped me understand some things. Hopefully someone will learn from this post too. Thanks guys !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`valeurs.cend` ([cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/end)) returns an instance to a `const_iterator` (that is, it's declared as `const_iterator valeurs.cend()`).

The compiler needs to create a [temporary object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8kfxa78%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) (memory area) to store the value returned by `valeurs.cend()`. This code fails to compile because you cannot take the reference of a temporary as the latter won't outlive the function call.

You'd usually return an iterator by value:

```
typedef typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator const_iterator;
const_iterator cend ( )
{
    return valeurs.cend ( );
}
```

This will make sure the value returned by `valeurs.cend()` is copied (or moved, in C++11, I believe) to its the destination object (if you're assigning the returned value to a variable of type `const_iterator`) or in another temporary wherever `Matrice<T>::cend()` is called. See the link to MSDN's explanation for details.

Answer (score 1):

hmjd is right, you need just const_iterator, not a reference. The reason you can't use a reference is that valeurs.cend () is a temporary value on the stack, the reference (if you could use it) wouldn't be valid as soon as the function returns.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, the following line:

```
const_iterator& cend ( )
```

Needs to be either:

```
const const_iterator& cend ( )
```

Or:

```
const_iterator cend ( )
```